# Embed custom RNN cell with _init_ that takes more arguments (3 vs 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to create a model similar to the one proposed in this paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8738842

The custom cell code is available at: https://github.com/SungjoonPark/DenoisingRNN/blob/master/dgrud.py

However, I am not able to embed this custom cell into any RNN model and I am assuming it is because the *init* takes 3 arguments instead of the standard "num_units".

I tried following the example at https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/:

```
cell = MinimalRNNCell(32)

x = keras.Input((None, 5))

layer = RNN(cell)

y = layer(x)
```

but I get an error:

> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in  2 x = keras.Input((None,
>   5)) 3 layer = RNN(cell) ----> 4 y = layer(x)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py in
>   call(self, inputs, initial_state, constants, **kwargs) 539 540 if
>   initial_state is None and constants is None: --> 541 return super(RNN,
>   self).call(inputs, **kwargs) 542 543 # If any of initial_state or
>   constants are specified and are Keras
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in
>   call(self, inputs, **kwargs) 487 # Actually call the layer, 488 #
>   collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s). --> 489 output =
>   self.call(inputs, **kwargs) 490 output_mask =
>   self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask) 491
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py in
>   call(self, inputs, mask, training, initial_state, constants) 680
>   mask=mask, 681 unroll=self.unroll, --> 682 input_length=timesteps) 683
>   if self.stateful: 684 updates = []
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py
>   in rnn(step_function, inputs, initial_states, go_backwards, mask,
>   constants, unroll, input_length) 3101 constants=constants, 3102
>   unroll=unroll, -> 3103 input_length=input_length) 3104 reachable =
>   tf_utils.get_reachable_from_inputs([learning_phase()], 3105
>   targets=[last_output])
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py
>   in rnn(step_function, inputs, initial_states, go_backwards, mask,
>   constants, unroll, input_length, time_major, zero_output_for_mask)
>   3730 # the value is discarded. 3731 output_time_zero, _ =
>   step_function( -> 3732 input_time_zero, tuple(initial_states) +
>   tuple(constants)) 3733 output_ta = tuple( 3734
>   tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py in
>   step(inputs, states) 671 else: 672 def step(inputs, states): --> 673
>   return self.cell.call(inputs, states, **kwargs) 674 675 last_output,
>   outputs, states = K.rnn(step,
>
> TypeError: call() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Could you please help me figure out whether it is a *init* issue, a *call* issue or I need to define a custom layer for this custom cell?

I tried looking for answers all over the internet and I just can't get any clarity on how embedding a custom cell in a RNN model should be done.

Thank you in advance,

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate your issue while I imported keras directly into the program. See below,

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import keras
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import RNN

class MinimalRNNCell(keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        self.units = units
        self.state_size = units
        super(MinimalRNNCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      name='kernel')
        self.recurrent_kernel = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units, self.units),
            initializer='uniform',
            name='recurrent_kernel')
        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs, states):
        prev_output = states[0]
        h = K.dot(inputs, self.kernel)
        output = h + K.dot(prev_output, self.recurrent_kernel)
        return output, [output]

# Let's use this cell in a RNN layer:

cell = MinimalRNNCell(32)
x = keras.Input((None, 5))
layer = RNN(cell)
y = layer(x)
```

Output -

```
TensorFlow is already loaded. Please restart the runtime to change versions.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-0f3bed686a7d> in <module>()
     34 x = keras.Input((None, 5))
     35 layer = RNN(cell)
---> 36 y = layer(x)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in symbolic_fn_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     73         if _SYMBOLIC_SCOPE.value:
     74             with get_graph().as_default():
---> 75                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     76         else:
     77             return func(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The error vanishes while you import keras `from tensorflow import keras`. The code runs successfully with tensorflow version 1.x and as well as 2.x.  Modify your code as below -

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import RNN

# First, let's define a RNN Cell, as a layer subclass.

class MinimalRNNCell(keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        self.units = units
        self.state_size = units
        super(MinimalRNNCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      name='kernel')
        self.recurrent_kernel = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units, self.units),
            initializer='uniform',
            name='recurrent_kernel')
        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs, states):
        prev_output = states[0]
        h = K.dot(inputs, self.kernel)
        output = h + K.dot(prev_output, self.recurrent_kernel)
        return output, [output]

# Let's use this cell in a RNN layer:

cell = MinimalRNNCell(32)
x = keras.Input((None, 5))
layer = RNN(cell)
y = layer(x)

print("I Ran Successfully")
```

Output -

```
I Ran Successfully
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @SCoder - Can you please accpet and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.